# How to insert current Timestamp in R?

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a function to insert the current time among keyboard shortcuts?
I didn't enter any syntax, but this code was generated.

*# Mon Aug 22 17:02:58 2022 ------------------------------*

I'd really like to know what this feature is.
This feature will be very helpful for my R work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sys.time()` + `format`:

```r
format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
# [1] "Mon Aug 22 11:13:52 2022"
```

In Rstudio, you can use that to do a [snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE). Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Edit Code Snippets</kbd>.

```r
snippet currentDate
    # Date: `r paste(format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))` ------------------
```

And then, in the script, type `currentDate` + <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```r
# Date: Mon Aug 22 11:17:18 2022 ------------------
```